# Can't relink mdb file with Linked File Wizard

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-connection, wizard

So, I've got an access database that I want to open.

I can see the querys/forms/tables exist but when I want to open them it tells me

"X:[...]\database.mdb" is not a valid path. Of course, because this is my computer. So when I select them to relink them in the wizard, I select the current database file and it just tells me, that the query/form/table doesn't exist in there and I should check the name.

But I am in that database and I can see those forms exist. The database itself is just around 1mb, is there something msissing maybe? Don't think so, huh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Access database project [has been split into **Front-End** and **Back-End** databases](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/databasesplitter/index.html).

This is normal practice for an Access database project of any significant size.

It seems you have the **front-end** database - this is the one containing the forms etc. Yes, it will list the tables but all those tables are just links. The underlying data is not in this front-end database, but in the **back-end**.

If your tables are shown with a small arrow then these are linked tables and a sure sign you have a front-end database:

[image]

When you fire up the Linked Table Wizard you need to browse to the back-end database, not the current database. If you cannot locate the back-end or no longer have it, then basically, you have no data. Your **front-end** database may be of little value on its own.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I just checked it, exactly what I thought it is but your description is just great. Thanks for that!